# Connect to Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I have 2 machines, one at Location A and the other at Location B. The B machine is connected to A's newtwork via VPN. VS2008 Team System is installed on both machines. The A machine has a menu option under **Tools** > **Connect to Team Foundation Server...** but the B machine does not have this option.

Is there something that I've missed in the installation of VS2008TS on the B machine? How does one enable this menu item?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you installed [Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0ED12659-3D41-4420-BBB0-A46E51BFCA86&displaylang=en)?  It's a separate install.

Comment: Yes, on the Visual Studio install disk, in a folder called TFC you can install the client.

Comment: Team Explorer is also called TFS Client Tools sometimes :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you set the source control plug-in properly?

Tools -> Options -> Source Control

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether or not Team Explorer is installed on machine B? You'll need that to connect to TFS.